# Don't understand why I am getting this - 'Error: Value storage corrupted: negative chunk size'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I'm using intelliJ IDEA version 9.0.1 build #IU 93.94 with JDK 1.6.0_17.

This error comes up at compile time. It only happens sometimes and sometimes when I hit File|Invalidate Caches and restart intelliJ, my project will build successfully.

I have absolutely no idea what to do about this, but it is slowing my progress down quite a bit. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the system directory manually including the compiler caches, then rebuild the project.

USERPROFILE\.IntelliJIdeaXX\system on Windows, ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIDEAXX on Mac OS X, ~/.IntelliJIdeaXX/system on Linux.

XX will be 90 for your IDEA version.

Comment: remove the entire USERPROFILE\.IntelliJIdeaXX\system directory and all of it's sub-directories?

or just the USERPROFILE\.IntelliJIdeaXX\system\caches directory?

Comment: Remove /index, /compiler and /caches subdirectories. If it doesn't help, remove the entire system directory.